# Chapter 1.2; Ross: 2nd Course in Probability

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

I would like to clarify on Ross' example of a non-measurable event.

> Consider a circle having radius equal to one. We say that two points
>   on the edge of the circle are in the same family if you can go from
>   one point to the other point by taking steps of length one unit around
>   the edge of the circle. By this we mean each step you take moves you
>   an angle of exactly one radian degree around the circle, and you are
>   allowed to keep looping around the circle in either direction.
>
> Suppose each family elects one of its members to be the head of the
>   family. Here is the question: what is the probability a point $X$ is
>   selected uniformly at random along the edge of the circle is the head
>   of its family? It turns out this question has no answer.

I can understand this example well. Ross then further clarified why the probability is undefined using the following equation:

> $$ \begin{align} 1 = P(A) + \sum_{i=1}^\infty(P(A_i) + P(B_i))
> \end{align} $$
>   Thus if $x = P(A)$, we get $1 = x + \sum_{i=1}^\infty 2x$, which has
>   no solution where $0 \leq x \leq 1$.

Which I also can understand.

My confusion here is that Ross' example seems to be overly and unnecessarily complicated. The idea here is that for disjoint events $A_1,A_2,\dots$, we must have $P(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty A_i) = \sum_{i=1}^\infty P(A_i) = 1$. I believe that the following example is much simpler: Consider the "uniform distribution over $\mathbb{Q}$", i.e. (roughly speaking) each rational number has an equal probability of being chosen. Then the probability of choosing a specific rational number must be undefined as $\mathbb{Q}$ is countable.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the most important thing, where you speak roughly : no such uniform distribution exists over the rationals, or even over a superset of the rationals, simply for the reason that the rationals are countable, and a countable sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty  x$ is either $0$ or $\infty$ for $0 \leq x \leq 1$. So there is no measure space on which we can conduct the operations specified by you. This is why Sheldon Ross can't give this particular thing as an example, *but* he can do something similar to the example he gives and which you attempt to give, which is done in other books.

Namely, take $[0,1]$ with the usual measure, and now say two points are in the same family if their absolute difference is a rational number. Then pick a head of each family, put the heads together in one set, and the probability of that set of heads $A \subset [0,1]$ can't be defined i.e. it is a non-measurable event.

The reason remains roughly the same : the sets of the form $x+A$ , for $x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]$, are disjoint, have the same measure as $A$ and have union $[0,1]$. Therefore, if $P(A) = y$ then $\sum_{x \in \mathbb Q \cap [0,1]} y = 1$, which can't be satisfied as the sum is countable.

Such a set $A$ is called a *Vitali set* (Note : A rational translate of a Vitali set is also a Vitali set, so no uniqueness holds). Note that we used the axiom of choice to "pick" a member of each family to put in the Vitali set. Without the axiom of choice, it's nice to know that Solovay has constructed a set model in which *all* sets are Lebesgue measurable, but the model doesn't include the axiom of choice.

For another example of a non-measurable set , see the Sierpinski construction of a non-measurable set.

Comment: So are you saying that my example is invalid because defining a "uniform distribution over $Q$" is not possible in the first place, but we can clearly define the example Ross gave?

Comment: Yes. The point is, what "uniformity" *means* in each of these circumstances is different. In the rational case, by uniform, you want to put the same weight on each rational number. This is *not possible*. In the circle case, uniform *does not mean that each point gets the same weight*, it means that each *arc* is weighted by its length, and therefore arcs of the same length get the same weight (so that is, the measure is uniform in that two arcs of the same length have the same measure). However, note that if I wanted each *point* to get uniform weight, I can't do that in the circle ,...

Comment: ... just because of the same reason as for the rationals (even stronger) : the circle contains uncountably many points. Finally, the uniform weight on arcs is *possible* : by Caratheodory extension theorem, defining the measure on arcs by their length, we can extend the measure to the sigma algebra defined by taking the arcs as a generating set. Note that the uniform weight on arcs gives each singleton a measure of zero, so this is not what uniformity on points should imply.